# How to iterate over azure.core.paging.ItemPaged and get the peering name?

Tags: azure, azure-python-sdk

I have created the below code but when I execute it it gives me an error as Iterator object.
If I apply for loop for data it doesn't give me any output.Any advice as how to pull data out of that object, I also explored the azure provided virtual network peering class but no luck.

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.subscription import SubscriptionClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient

credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(credential)

subs_id = 'xxxxxxxx'

network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subs_id)
data = network_client.virtual_network_peerings.list('resourcegroup','virtualnetwork')
print(data)
```

Output:
<iterator object azure.core.paging.ItemPaged at 0x210a5fe1570>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over azure.core.paging.ItemPaged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766541/how-to-iterate-over-azure-core-paging-itempaged)

Comment: [How should Azure ItemPaged iterator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938321/how-should-azure-itempaged-iterator-work)